# Induction proof fibonacci numbers

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

I need to prove the following with induction:

n∑i=1 F(2i-1) = F(2n) for all n >= 1

I am stuck in my inductive step:

- n∑i=1 F(2i-1) =  n∑i=1 F(2i-1) + F(2(n + 1) -1)
- = F(2n)         + F(2(n + 1)-1)
- = F(2n)         + F(2n + 1)

I am trying to get to F(2n + 2).

I know the following recursive definition of Fibonacci numbers:
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2), How can I use it to reach my answer?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Um, you already have. F(2n + 2) by definition = F(2n + 1) + F(2N).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement seems to be
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n F(2i-1)=F(2n),\qquad n\ge1
$$
The base case, $n=1$, is obvious because $F(1)=1$ and $F(2)=1$.

Assume it's the case for $n$; then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} F(2i-1)=
\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{n} F(2i-1)\biggr)+F(2(n+1)-1)=
F(2n)+F(2n+1)
$$
and the definition of the Fibonacci sequence gives the final step:
$$
F(2n)+F(2n+1)=F(2n+2)=F(2(n+1))
$$

Comment: Oh ok, so whats helped me most is that you can justify the final step by the definition of a Fibonacci sequence. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sum up the recurrence relations:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i}=\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-2}=\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} F_{2i}$$
As $F_0=0$,  this equality simplifies to:
$$F_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^n F_{2i-1}.$$